# Funny things happening with putExtra and getIntExtra

Tags: android

I'm developing a game, on my menu screen I have a series of buttons which take the player to different levels of the game. I've used putExtra and getIntExtra to take an Int from the menu activity to the game activity, this then sets the play level.

This is all working nicely, the problem I am having is when using the "back" button to go back to the menu activity you have to hit it twice to get to the menu instead of once. If you hit it once it takes you to the level which corresponds with the default Int of the getIntExtra function.

I'm not sure why it's doing this.

Any advice would be appreciated.

-- Edit --

In Menu Activity

```
 public void onGoToGame1Click(View view) {

    Intent getNameScreenIntent = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);

    final int result = 1;
    startActivityForResult(getNameScreenIntent, result);

    getNameScreenIntent.putExtra( "int", 1);
    startActivity(getNameScreenIntent);
}
```

In Game Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_layout);

    levelTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.level);

    Intent getNameScreenIntent = getIntent();
    level = getNameScreenIntent.getIntExtra("int", 1);

    levelTV.setText(" " + level);

}

private void levelUpdate() {

    switch (score) {

        case 10:
            level = 2;
            break;
        case 20:
            level = 3;
            break;
        case 30:
            level = 4;
            break;
        case 40:
            level = 5;
            break;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a few code examples. Especially how you use the putExtra/getIntExtra functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use both `startActivityForResult()` and `startActivity()`, so your activities will be started twice.
The first time without extra, the second with the extra.

You should choose one or the other. `startActivityForResult()` should be used only if you need the  activity to give you a result back when it finishes.

**Side note:** the second parameter of `startActivityForResult()` is not the result. It is a request code that allows the caller to know which request was answered when it gets a callback to `onActivityResult()`.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use this line?

```
 startActivityForResult(getNameScreenIntent, result);
```

Because you start two activites by using the above and startActivity() you end up with two GamingActivities with one on top of the other. When you use the back button you close the upper on and the application shows the other activity you started. If you want to use the Extra you should use only startActivity().